# Git is not allowing local changes to be committed or pushed

Tags: git

I am having an issue with a local git repository.  I am trying to make a change to a file and it either won't commit the file or if I add the file and the commit it the remote won't accept it.

I start by creating the local repo using clone or pull.

```
$ mkdir {projectDir}
$ cd {projectDir}/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in F:/{projectDir}/.git/
$ git remote add origin {account}@{ssh-host}:/var/repo/{projectName}
$ git pull origin master
From {ssh-host}:/var/repo/{projectName}
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
```

Then I make a minor change

```
$ vi pub/index.php (small change to an existing file)
```

Then I attempt to commit the change

```
$ git commit -m 'minor change'
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   pub/index.php

no changes added to commit
```

When I look around StackExchange I find a bunch of suggestions to add the file to the local repo, which is weird because the file exists already.  But I do it anyway and I get

```
$ git add pub/index.php 
$ git commit -m 'minor change'
[master 4efd2ac] minor change
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

ok.  So then I try to push it and it demonstrates its hatred for me.

```
$ git push origin master
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To {account}@{ssh-host}:/var/repo/{projectName}
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '{account}@{ssh-host}:/var/repo/{projectName}'
```

Following the advice in there just puts me back to square one and nothing I do seems to be able to get the local and remote repos to sync up properly.

Comment: As @David Deutsch points out, you shouldn't init a new repo. Just skip git init and git add remote origin and use git clone {account}@{ssh-host}:/var/repo/{projectName} instead of git pull.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work.  It seems like the problem was that somehow the remote got checked out on its local machine... probably by me when I was trying to fix a Jenkins build issue earlier this morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set up a non-bare repository as your remote, which (as the error says) does not accept pushes to its currently checked out branch. What you need to do is instead clone from a bare repo; chances are very good that `{account}@{ssh-host}:/var/repo/{projectName}` itself points to a bare repo for *its* remote; if so, use that one (assuming you have access to that machine).

Also, FWIW, you indeed need to either `git add` a file after you change it, or use `git commit -a`. I know it seems strange since the file is already in the repo, but it is your current *version* of the file that you are adding.

Comment: I've always taken the git add command as "add to the next commit". It's how you select files and their revisions for committing.

Comment: I think I get it.  My remote repo was checked out on the local server.  So when I would try to push the changes it would decline it (for the reasons you stated).  I checked out the remote to a different branch (on its local copy) and I was able to push the changes.

Comment: @KevinSchroeder - While that workaround might work, it would be far better to create a bare repository on the server with `git init --bare`, then point both `{account}@{ssh-host}:/var/repo/{projectName}` and your local repo to it as their remote. That way you can push/pull to/from any branch you want.

Comment: I had tried doing that earlier but it didn't like it when I tried to push my local changes over.  There is about two months of work on existing remote repo and I'm not sure how I would merge my existing changes onto the new repo I'd be using as the origin.

Comment: Due to the distributed nature of git, it's easy; just point either of your repos to the new bare repo with `git remote add origin`, then `git push --all -u origin`.

Comment: ... odd, that worked now.  I wonder if the -u flag was what made the difference...